# RDS Host Excel previewer blocks Excel from starting

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, rds, microsoft-office-2013

I have a RDS Host, Windows 2012R2 and Office 2013 with the following issue:

1. User opens File Explorer
2. User selects a Excel file so that the Previewer pane shows the contents of the file.
3. User doubleclicks on the file, nothing happens. If the users deselects the file in the File Explorer Excel starts and opens the File.

Strange thing is this happens only the for the first Excel viewed in the Preview pane. If you select another Excel file and try to open that one it works fine, opening the next Excel also file works just fine (even if shown in the Preview Pane). Untill you close the File Explorer and open another one.

The files reside on a local drive for the RDS host. One solution would be disabling the Preview pane but that would interrupt the workflow for the users.

I Googled for this issue, but this specific issue I haven't seen. I did add the following registery keys (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/2012/05/14/the-definitive-locked-file-post-updated-772014/) :

```
Key: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{993BE281-6695-4BA5-8A2A-7AACBFAAB69E} 
Name: EnableShareDenyNone  
Type: REG_DWORD  
Value: 1

Key: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{993BE281-6695-4BA5-8A2A-7AACBFAAB69E} 
Name: NoOpLock 
Type: REG_DWORD  
Value: 1
```

Updates are installed. Users with limited and admin rights have this issue. The file location is a trusted location in Excel.

Comment: The pane preview actually keep a lock on the file as its open to create the preview, can you just disable the pane preview ?

Comment: Of course I could. But the organization is very Excel driven and the preview pane is used a lot. 

The strange thing is, this only happens with the first Excel file that is selected. Every other Excel file thereafter works. So I am hoping this I some kind of bug.

Also I can't reproduce this on other systems, there it just works, even if the file is open in the Preview pane. 

Hope this clarifies it.